# How can I update only specific portion of a page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using two update panels in my aspx page. My page also contains other controls most of them are text boxes. some text boxes using ajaxwater mark extender. My problem is when the portion of the panels is updated the watermark textbox also updated. How can I preven this to happen?
My page is like
    
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
    
                                
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
....some other controls and then

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelTestRoll">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <fieldset style="height: 70px; float: left; width: 350px;">
                                <legend>Submission</legend>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubmitted" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <label for="chkSubmitted">
                                    Submitted</label>
                                <label for="txtSubmissionDate">
                                    Submission Date</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubmissionDate" runat="server" Height="12px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtSubmissionDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                    TargetControlID="txtSubmissionDate">
                                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkTestToAppear" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px" />
                            <label for="">
                                Test To Appear</label>--%>
                                <br />
                                <label for="txtAdmissionTestRoll">
                                    Admission Test Roll
                                </label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdmissionTestRoll" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What to do to optimize the code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you only want to update parts of the page, you have to call [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) on the appropriate UpdatePanel(if set to Conditional). If the control you don't want to update is inside this UpdatePanel, you have to divide it into two UpdatePanels, so that only the correct one is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [UpdatePanel.UpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) to Conditional.

> The content of the UpdatePanel control is updated under the following
>   conditions: If the Update method of the UpdatePanel control is called
>   explicitly.
>
> If a control is defined as a trigger by using the Triggers property of
>   the UpdatePanel control and causes a postback. In this scenario, the
>   control is an explicit trigger for updating the panel content. The
>   trigger control can be either inside or outside the UpdatePanel
>   control that defines the trigger.
>
> If the ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true and a child control
>   of the UpdatePanel control causes a postback. In this scenario, child
>   controls of the UpdatePanel control are implicit triggers for updating
>   the panel. Child controls of nested UpdatePanel controls do not cause
>   the outer UpdatePanel control to be updated unless they are explicitly
>   defined as triggers.